# Problem regarding convergence of second order

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, roots, newton-raphson

> Show $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$ with start value $x_0=1$ and $f:x\to x^5$ does not converge quadratically.

So by definition I have to show that $\mid x_{n+1}-0\mid\le c \mid x_n -0\mid^2$ for quadratic convergence, I guess.
Plugging in leads to $\mid x -\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\mid=\mid x-\frac x5\mid=\frac45 \mid x\mid\le c \mid x \mid^2$ And since $x$ will get never negative in this iteration we can write above as  $\frac45 x\le c x^2 \Rightarrow \frac45 \le cx$, but with this reasing I could set $c=\frac 1x$ and therefore this convergence would be quadratic. I am oviously on the wrong track. Could someone help me and guide me, what exactly I have to do here?

Comment: You do realize that with your existing steps you are exactly right, as the task is to rule out quadratic convergence?

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean. My approach did not solve this task, I think.

Comment: You are asked to prove a negative, that a counter-example works as such. Computing $x_{n+1}=\frac45 x_n$ does just that.

Comment: I still do not get your point. I want to show that $f$ does not converge quadratically. I showed $\mid x_{n+1}\mid = \mid \frac45 x_n \mid$, but why does this show that it does not converge quadratically. Could you tell me what  expression there had to be instead, if it would converge quadratially?

Comment: I added a new question, maybe this will enlighten me about this topic! See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2630008/rate-of-convergence-in-newton-raphson

Answer (score 1):

Suppose
$f(x) = x^m$
with $m \gt 1$.
Then
$f'(x)
= mx^{m-1}
$.

If
$x_{n+1}
=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}
$
then
$x_{n+1}
=x_n-\frac{x_n^m}{mx_n^{m-1}}
=x_n-\frac{x_n}{m}
=x_n(1-\frac{1}{m})
=x_n(\frac{m-1}{m})
$
so that
$\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}
=\frac{m-1}{m}
\gt 0
$
and the convergence is linear.

The fact that
$\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}
=\frac{m-1}{m}
\lt 1
$
shows that the iteration
converges from any starting point.

Answer (score 0):

$$x_{n+1}=\dfrac{4}{5}x_n$$so obviously $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$$starting from any initial condition, but $x_{n+1}$ is not proportional to $x_n^2$ so the convergence is not quadratic.